# Generar un diccionario a partir de un dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataframe que guarda un valor para cada columna con la siguiente forma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi intención es generar un diccionario, pues van a ser valores que se ven a emplear bastante.

Encontré la existencia de [pandas.DataFrame.to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-to-dict). Pero esto me generar un diccionario el cual a su vez genera otro con el valor y fila. De la siguiente forma:

```
{'australian pull ups': {0: 10}, 'pull ups': {0: 4}, 'muscle ups': {0: 0}, 'push ups': {0: 12}, 'dips': {0: 8}, 'air squats': {0: 30}, 'pistol squats': {0: 2}, 'knee to elbows': {0: 10}, 'toes to bar': {0: 0}}
```

Yo simplemente quiero nombre y valor obviando la fila, pues solo hay una.

También lo he hecho de manera manual y sale bien, pero obviamente no es optimo.

```
marcas_padres = {}
x1 = marcas.loc[0]['pull ups']
x2 = marcas.loc[0]['push ups']
marcas_padres.update({'pull ups': x1})
marcas_padres.update({'push ups': x2})
```

Resultado:

```
{'pull ups': 4, 'push ups': 12}
```

En la manera manual sale exactamente lo que quiero, pero ¿como puedo hacerlo sin tener que meterlo uno a uno? ¿Hay una función de `pandas` que me solucione esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tú quieres hacer es:

```
dataframe.to_dict(orient='records')
```

El método **to_dict()** puede utilizarse con distintos parametros para que te forme un diccionario distinto. Hay hasta 6 parametros distintos, El que tú quieres es **records**

Puedes ver el resto en [la documentación oficial de pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Comment: El único problema es que me crea el diccionario dentro de una lista `[{'australian pull ups': 10, ' pull ups': 4, ' muscle ups': 0}...]` entonces no puedo luego hacer un `.get()` para trabajar con las keys... ¿Se te ocurre como solucionar esto?

Comment: Hice `print(marcas_padres[0].get())` pero imagino no es lo más correcto... ¿o si?

Comment: Sí lo que quieres es imprimir el resultado en consola está bien. El get necesita una clave para devolverte el valor de dicha clave. Yo lo hago así: marcas_padres[0]['australian pull ups'] y me devolvería el valor de esa clave, que en este caso es 10, pero lo que tú has hecho es correcto (siempre que vaya el valor de una clave en el get)

Answer (score 3):

Tienes diferentes opciones para pasarle al metodo to_dict() y que te devuelva la salida en diferentes configuraciones, te pongo cómo te saldrían:

**df.to_dict()**

```
  {'australian pull ups': {0: 10}, ' pull ups': {0: 4}, ' muscle ups': {0: 0}...
```

**df.to_dict(orient="list")** o **df.to_dict('l')**

```
{'australian pull ups': [10], ' pull ups': [4], ' muscle ups': [0]...
```

**df.to_dict(orient="series")** o **df.to_dict('s')**

```
{'australian pull ups': 0    10
Name: australian pull ups, dtype: int64, ' pull ups': 0    4
Name:  pull ups, dtype: int64, ' muscle ups': 0    0
Name:  muscle ups, dtype: int64...
```

**df.to_dict(orient="split")** o **df.to_dict('sp')**

```
{'index': [0], 'columns': ['australian pull ups', ' pull ups', ' muscle ups'...], 'data': [[10, 4, 0...]]
```

**df.to_dict(orient="records")** o **df.to_dict('r')**

```
[{'australian pull ups': 10, ' pull ups': 4, ' muscle ups': 0}...]
```

**df.to_dict(orient="index")** o **df.to_dict('i')**

```
{0: {'australian pull ups': 10, ' pull ups': 4, ' muscle ups': 0...}}
```

Las más parecidas a lo que estás buscando serían `records` o `index`